# Changing the order of items in an ordered list incorrectly shows additional list items in the inline diff view

Tags: bug, revisions-list, diff

I have an ordered list of 3 items below. However, I later realized that the item which I initially wrote as the first in the list is actually the least important and should be at the end, so I edited the question.

1. Reiciendis voluptatibus
2. Libero tempore
3. Lorem ipsum

### Issue

In the inline revision diff, we can see the following:

[image: Screenshot]

This is confusing because at first glance it seems to imply that the list once had 4 items while it never did. Also, the diff does not correctly show the change in the numbering of the items.

### Expectation

This is what I expect the inline diff to look like:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is not a bug but a feature. A feature of HTML and the browsers that render the HTML.

It is worth noting that numbered lists can have an arbitrary start number

4. Foo
5. Bar
6. FuBar

Markdown of above list:

```
4. Foo
8. Bar
11. FuBar
```

The inline view does what it promises: It shows you the HTML of an ordered list with list items that are removed and added. The numbering is at the mercy of the browser, not of the editor. The inline can't and shouldn't try to break up the ordered list to maintain numbering because that will undoubtedly change the  appearance of ordered lists making it even harder to judge what is being done. "Fixing" this bug will break the usability and purpose of that view, even for ordered lists.

When in doubt, any reviewer or visitor can either:

- use the Side-By-Side view:

[image: side by side showing red first line of the list on the left and green last line on the right]

- use the Side-By-Side Markdown view

[image: side by side markdown view showing red list left and green list the right]

and those views clearly shows what happened in any case where the inline view leaves doubts. As a matter of fact I hardly ever use the inline view to judge changes.

The bug, as reported, shouldn't be fixed to prevent the inline view from becoming irreparable.